# typescript: Read class decorator files in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, decorator

I've created a class decorator to read the permission for the angular component.

**decorator.ts**

```js
function permissions(object: { [key: 'read' | 'write' | 'update' | 'delete']: string }[]) {
    return (ctor: Function) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
    }
}
```

**components.ts**

```js
// employee.component.ts
@permissions([{ read: 'read-unique-id' }])
@Component({
    selector: 'app-employee',
    templateUrl: './app-employee.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-employee.component.css']
})
class Employee {
    constructor() { }
}

// employee-details.component.ts
@permissions([{ read: 'read-unique-id' }, { write: 'write-unique-id' }])
@Component({
    selector: 'app-employee-details',
    templateUrl: './app-employee-details.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-employee-details.component.css']
})
class EmployeeDetails {
    constructor() { }
}
```

I should be creating a file by reading the class name along with the permission details from decorator during compilation. Just a command to generate the below file.

Example: **Permissions.ts**

```js
class Permissions {
    static EMPLOYEE_READ = 'read-unique-id';
    static EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_READ = 'read-unique-id';
    static EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_WRITE = 'write-unique-id';
}
```

I believe I should create a Node JS app to read all the files and check for @permissions decorator and generate the above file. Is that correct?

If so, Can someone help me to achieve that. Read all the component.ts file and get the permissions details or is there any other method to achieve the same.

> Update: I should read permission details from **component.ts** through **decorator** and generate **Permissions.ts** with help of **Node JS** app.

Comment: I 'm confused . which file do you want to read and which file you want to generate ?

Comment: You could use regexps (yikes), or https://github.com/mgechev/ngast, or or Angular schematics, https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2 , or any TypeScript AST. But it's unclear where you expect to get names like EMPLOYEE_READ. Any way, this seems to be a roundabout that is type-unsafe and prone to typos.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated my post. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: It's still unclear where EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_READ comes from. Is it supposed to analyze class name and get 'EMPLOYEE_DETAILS' part from 'EmployeeDetails'? Any way, the comment above is still applicable. It's likely possible but the solution will be clumsy, unreliable and suffer from inconsistencies (there can be multiple classes with same name, or classes with different name that should have same permission).

Comment: EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_READ will be constructed from Class name + key of the decorator. i.e. EmployeeDetails + read => EmployeeDetails_READ.

Answer (score 0):

A more simple and type-safe way is to move in opposite direction and use a set of constants instead of strings, e.g. with `enum`:

```
enum Permissions {
    EMPLOYEE_READ = 'read-unique-id';
    ...
}

...

@permissions([{ read: Permissions.EMPLOYEE_READ }, ...}])
```

A module that contains constants can be reused in backend application as well.

Comment: Permission will be defined in front-end, so FE will generate a JSON file out of **permission.ts** or **decorator** and and back-end will read it from JSON and insert in DB.

Comment: I'm not sure how this approach can be more beneficial than having permission constant that acts as single source of truth. The latter can be used in FE with type checks and can be inserted to DB explicitly (e.g. with a migration) or implicitly (e.g. on server start).

Comment: I was using your suggested approach before, but the problem I've faced here is whenever new page or component creates Permission should be updated in the enum file. Also, I should have a mapping table to map the permissions to the component. If the permission is defined using a decorator, then the mapping file is not required. I somehow read the class name with the permission defined.

Comment: Yes, that's how it's usually done. Too much magic results in inconsistencies, especially on the large scale. Another approach is to use DB as single source of truth. It can be automatically exported to JSON, and JSON imports are properly typed since TS 2.9.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for a large scale. I feel the approach which I've taken will suit my requirement. It's similar to how component decorator used to get selector, templateUrl and so on. Appreciate your support.

Comment: Then consider using tools suggested in this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785608/typescript-read-class-decorator-files-in-node-js/50786494?noredirect=1#comment88579430_50785608